# populate cells from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to populate a worksheet with a calculation based on 2 cells in another worksheet within teh saem workbook.

In worksheet one I have a table with 'Last Month' and 'This Month' that contain number of infections. I need the percentage difference to populate in the other worksheet. Is this possible?

A BIG thank you for any help.

Maggie

Comment: Not that I'm able to help as I'm not an excel guru, but what have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter? Please see http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 'Last Month' worksheet has the number of infections in cell B2, you could do the following from any other worksheet in the workbook:

```
=('Last Month'!B2)
```

That tells Excel to look in the worksheet called "Last Month", and retrieve the value from cell B2. You can also use this in formulae like =SUM(C77+'Last Month'!B2), which will add the value of cell C77 in the current worksheet, to the value of cell B2 in the "Last Month" worksheet.
NB: You will need the single quotes ('') around *Last Month* because it has a space in it. If the worksheet were called "LastMonth", you would not need them.